# In phone gap html page take too much time to load

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I am making application using phone gap in which certain html pages in asset folder of project. and I am using the code below. but it takes too much time in loading.
can any one give proper solution ?
Thanks!

```
public class JvdActivity extends DroidGap {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    KeyBoard keyboard = new KeyBoard(this, appView);
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(keyboard, "KeyBoard");
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If their are lots Images inside the HTML page then to load that page Inside the screen It takes Time.

But if it is requirement of your project then you will use progress bar saying Loading.. so that user can wait till the page gets loaded.