# Android, Phonegap1.4.1 after using splash screen i get a blank screen for 1-2 sec

Tags: android, cordova

I get a blank screen on android after splash screen.

On ios i am using navigator.splashscreen, but this is not available on android.

How can I do this on android?

I am using sencha 1.1.1, phonegap 1.4.1 and android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please go through with the below link : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429555/in-phone-gap-html-page-take-too-much-time-to-load/9429730#9429730

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this when I was using Sencha was to set a background-image on the body tag in your main index.html file that matches the Phonegap splashscreen.

```
body {
  background-image: url('splash.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:top;
}
```

Then once your application has finished loading it fills the body tag, which hides the background image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I give it a try. But there is still a problem with android device resolutions, it always uses the same image .. but this solution is still better than the blank screen. thanks

Comment: You can always include several images and target the body with media queries in order to apply different resolution images